# Ubuntu 16.04 Samsung R580 Display Brightness Keyboard Shortcut Issues

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, shortcut-keys, display, brightness

I have read many posts on the display brightness keyboard shortcuts issues in Ubuntu. Most have answers for Ubuntu 14 or prior, so I want to include as much information as possible.

## What Happens

Upon boot, I login and brightness adjustment keyboard shortcuts are ineffective and brightness is at max. I logout (without restarting), log back in, and the keyboard shortcuts are effective.

## What Should Happen

Whether first, second, third, or additional login, keyboard shortcuts for brightness control should work without having to log out and log back in.

## Background Details

- ***Computer:*** Samsung NP-R580-JSB1US
- ***OS + type:*** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit
- ***Graphics:*** GeForce 310M/PCIe/SSE2
- ***Graphics Driver:*** NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96 from nvidia-340 (proprietary, tested)
- ***Keyboard Shortcut(s):*** <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> | <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>
- ***NVidia Conf Location:*** `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf`
- ***NVidia Conf Contents:***

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 361.42  (buildd@lgw01-18)  Tue Apr  5 14:33:28 UTC 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Chi Mei Optoelectronics corp."
    HorizSync       30.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 310M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This file was generated by the *NVidia X Server Settings Application* as you can see by the file comment-header, but was modified with the `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` and then saved to the indicated location (because I gathered through research that this was the new way of storing these `.conf` files).

## Conclusion

This is more of an annoyance than anything else, but if anyone else has experienced this or has an idea of where I can begin to look for a solution, please let me know.

Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a similar R580 and the same setup as you describe. Additionally I added this line in /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1366x768-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap acpi_backlight=vendor " and I installed the samsung-tools package.
With this the backlight keys work already after booting